# Why is the Uzumaki clan symbol more like a trademark in Konoha

Tags: naruto

Almost every Ninja's cloth (mostly Jounin and chunin gear) have the Uzumaki clan (red-swirly circlish spiral) on their backs and I've been wondering why for a while now.

The clan sybol can be seen on the shoulders and the back of the Jonin Flak jacket.
[image]

Since the Uchiha and Senjuu clan founded the hidden leaf, one would expect that at least one of those clans symbol would be the trademark of the hidden leaf or maybe even a combination of the 2 clans symbol.

But rather they chose a clan that is affiliated with the land of eddies to be their symbol? What was the reasoning behind this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The Uzumaki, being descendants of Asura Ōtsutsuki, also shared distant blood relation with the Senju clan. Through the years, the Uzumaki and Senju kept close ties, with members at times marrying between clans, as with Hashirama Senju and Mito Uzumaki. Following the founding of Konohagakure at the end of the Warring States Period, the Senju chose to symbolise their clans' friendship by adding the Uzumaki's emblem to Konoha's flak jackets. Konoha and the Uzumaki's own Uzushiogakure remained close allies over the following decades, with the Uzumaki providing fūinjutsu (among other things) to Konoha whenever there was a need.

[Wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Uzumaki_Clan)